# Почему не отправляется сообщение с подтверждением на почту?

Tags: python, django, email

Хочу зарегистрироваться по почте, все делал по этому гайду, только setting.py немного отличается, покажу ниже

https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-signup-user-and-send-confirmation-email-in-django

Инспектор не показывает никаких красных ошибок, но почему-то на почту не приходит сообщение и регистрация проходит без подтверждения почты

**setting.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
MAILER_EMAIL_BACKEND = EMAIL_BACKEND
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassfromemail'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

**models.py**

```
import kwargs as kwargs
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from datetime import datetime, date


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()

class Post(models.Model):
    published = None
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    body = models.TextField()
    header_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/")
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '|' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
        return reverse('home')


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

**myblog/views.py**

```
from pyexpat.errors import messages

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm, SignUpForm

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth import login

from django.utils.encoding import  force_text
from django.utils.http import  urlsafe_base64_decode



from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import View, UpdateView
from .forms import SignUpForm


from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string



from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode
from .tokens import account_activation_token

class ActivateAccount(View):

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            user.profile.email_confirmed = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('Your account have been confirmed.'))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, ('The confirmation link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.'))
            return redirect('home')


class SignUpView(View):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)

            messages.success(request, ('Please Confirm your email to complete registration.'))

            return redirect('login')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})



class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'post_comment.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    #fields = '__all__'

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

from myblog.forms import SignUpForm


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

**myblog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url


from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDeleteView,
    BlogCommentView,
    SignUpView,
    ActivateAccount

)


urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', BlogCommentView.as_view(), name='post_comment'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),

    url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/$', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', ActivateAccount.as_view(), name='activate'),


]
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUpView


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),

]
```

Я не знаю какие файлы помогут вам решить проблему, потому что я все еще на начальном этапе изучения django, поэтому скажите пожалуйста что вам показать и я сразу покажу вам любой файл

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте отправить через https://mailtrap.io/ . Там есть сгенерированный конфиг для django, копируете его себе в настройки и отправляете. Если отправится - смотрите в свои настройки SMTP

Comment: а так, был бы гугл - подсказал. с яндексовским сервером не работал

Comment: Помимо всего прочего в настройках Яндекса нужно разрешить доступ почтовым программам иначе работать не будет. Этот момент учли? В гугле или в яндексе (вот уж не помню) скрипты примерно так и ведут себя как Вы описали.

Comment: я включал какой то портальный пароль итп другие настройки, не помню, у меня уже другая ошибка 

`SMTPNotSupportedError at /accounts/signup/
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`

Вы случайно не знаете как пофиксить данную ошибку

Comment: Посмотрите вот это  https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients/others.html может быть поможет.